# How to change eth0 interface to bridge interface br0 with static IP in Ubuntu14.04

Tags: 14.04, networking, ethernet, interface, network-bridge

I need to change the network interface in Ubuntu 14.04 from eth0 to br0 bridge interface. I tried to install bridge-utils package but I couldn't find that package. Can anyone help how change it to br0 with static IP address.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please post the output of `apt-cache search bridge-utils`

Comment: @Kev Inski, Thanks for the commenting. I couldn't find that package in ubuntu. I downloaded that package (.deb) and installed it, after that made some changes in interface file, luckily it worked me.

Answer (score 0):

After giving some try finally got it worked.

**Solution:**
1. Install bridge-utils package, if ubuntu couldn't locate the package download and install it manually. For packages go through the [link](https://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/bridge-utils)

2. Make changes in interface file /etc/network/interfaces by replacing

**For Static IP**

auto br0

iface br0 inet static

```
address 10.x.x.x
    netmask 255.x.x.x
    broadcast 10.x.x.x
    dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 
    bridge_ports eth0
    bridge_stp off
    bridge_fd 0
    bridge_maxwait 0
```

**For Dynamic IP:**

auto br0

iface br0 inet dhcp

```
    bridge_ports eth0
    bridge_stp off
    bridge_fd 0
    bridge_maxwait 0
```

Thanks!